Expected number of edges of the convex hull
Pick $n$ points at random in a bounded region according to a given  probability distribution.
As $n \to \infty$, what is the limiting distribution of the number of edges (or vertices) of the convex hull formed by these points?
I am aware of results on the expected number of vertices chosen uniformly at random, such as those discussed in this question, but I am curious on how changing the way you pick points affects the limiting distribution of the number of edges in the convex hull.
